# Three divs in centered main div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a very new programmer (week and a half in), so sorry if this is inane. What I want is a main div with fixed width (and auto margins on each side to center it) and 3 other divs with fixed width inside. The right and middle are aligned but the left pushes it to a new line. Already tried changing display to inline block and changing main div's width to much larger than it should be.

```css
body {
  background-color: #D2B48C;
}

#main {
  width: 700px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#mainImage {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

#left img {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 600px;
}

#right img {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
    <button><img src="images/left.svg"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="mainImage">
    <!-- <img src="images/cat1.jpg"> -->
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button><img src="images/right.svg"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very basic question. I don't see why it should warrant an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` elements are **[block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** (meaning that they are each rendered on their own line of the document).

You can alter this default layout in a couple of ways.

You are currently using CSS `float`, however this technique has issues and, these days, is more trouble than its worth in many cases.

Another way is to use `<span>` elements for the inner containers instead of `<div>` elements as `<span>` elements are **["inline elements"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)** are are rendered "inline" (from left to right).

You could leave the inner elements as `<div>` elements, but alter their layout by using CSS and setting them to `display:inline` and they will then render as inline elements.

You can also solve the problem by very simply adding one CSS instruction that uses the **[Flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)** as shown below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #D2B48C;
}

#main {
  width: 700px;
  height: 600px;
  
  /* Simply setting the container to display its content in a flex box solve the problem! */
  display:flex;
}

#mainImage {

  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

#left img {

  width: 50px;
  height: 600px;
}

#right img {

  width: 50px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
    <button><img src="images/left.svg"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="mainImage">
    <!-- <img src="images/cat1.jpg"> -->
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button><img src="images/right.svg"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need your 3 siblings element to float *(or at least the first 2 and let 3rd use room left if enough)* , else they do behave as normal block:

```css
body {
  background-color: #D2B48C;
}

#main {
  width: 700px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#mainImage {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

#left, #left img {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 600px;
}

#right, #right img {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
    <button><img src="images/left.svg"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="mainImage">
    <!-- <img src="images/cat1.jpg"> -->
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button><img src="images/right.svg"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`display: table` + `table-cell` / `flex` / `grid` are also options instead `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You are really close and doing a great job for 1.5 weeks. Your only problem is that you are floating and applying the width to the image instead of the div wrapping it.

HTML elements come with default styles and there are two that are preventing you from achieving what you want. `<div>` are block level elements so if you don't float them you will have some wrapping going on. Also, even if you float the `<div>` you will have some overlap because `<button>` have default padding that will increase the width of your `<div>` to be 50px + padding from the button. Try this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #D2B48C;
}

#main {
  width: 700px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#mainImage, #left, #right {
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  width: 50px;
}

#mainImage {
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  width: 600px;
}

#left img, #left button, #right img, #right button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
    <button><img src="images/left.svg"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="mainImage">
    <!-- <img src="images/cat1.jpg"> -->
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button><img src="images/right.svg"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should've seen that.